# Powershell - List subdirectories and count files per subdirectory

Tags: file, powershell, directory, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I have a directory full of subdirectories that have any number of 0 to 300 files in them.

I want to output the subdirectory name and the number of files in that subdirectory

What I have so far is giving me 0 no matter how many actual files are in the subdirectory.

```
$dir = "C:\Folder\" 
$subFiles = (Get-ChildItem $dir -recurse | where-object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true })
$subFiles | % {
Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Force -Recurse | Measure-Object | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Count
write-host "$_"
}
```

Its also sometimes including the directories in which the script is being run ie "C:\Users\Blah\documents and settings\startmen" and causing errors.

Any help greatly appreciated thank you

Answer (score 6):

You are using at least PowerShell 3.0 since you are using the `-File` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` so you dont need to use the `where-object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true }`. That has been replaced with the `-Directory` parameter. Loop through all the folders and collect the folder name and count of its files. I removed the `-Recurse` of the file count since that could be misleading. Put it back if it suits you better. The final `Select-Object` is to ensure the order of the output which is an object now that you could sort or do whatever you wanted with.

```
$dir = "C:\File" 
Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Folder = $_.FullName
        Count = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Fullname -File).Count
    }
} | Select-Object Folder,Count
```

**Insight**

You were getting those errors before since you were not calling the full path in `Get-ChildItem` you were just calling the folder name. In the absence of a full path `Get-ChildItem` assumes you are looking for a folder in the current directory. That which is typically your user directory.

Comment: Hi Matt. Any chance you can modify the script to include just the subfolders immediately inside the supplied path?

Comment: @mrjayviper That's easy. Just use the `-Depth` parameter of `Get-ChildItem`

Comment: I tried using "-depth 1" (also tried 2) on first and second gci in your sample script and no difference to the original script.

Comment: @mrjayviper Perhaps I misunderstood but do you maybe just need to remove `-Recurse`? That should only process immediate subfolders.

Comment: example: parent1 (topmost folder) with 3 subfolders (subfolder1 subfolder2 and subfolder3). inside subfolder1 to 3 are many more folders and files. I want to display the number of files inside subfolder1 to 3. I tried without -recurse and it gave me a count of 0 for all the subfolders immediately underneath the path.

Comment: Let me look into this more in about an hour or so.

Comment: I get the results I expect when I use depth with this code. It shows the _file count_ in the root of each folder. The count is not recursive. I used `-Depth 1` and got results for 2 folders deep from the `$dir`

Answer (score 1):

This method for count seems to be faster for remote directories.

```
$count = [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles($_.Fullname).Count
```

Answer (score 0):

This did exactly what I wanted :) Its not very pretty, but it worked..

```
$dir = "C:\folder\"
$subFiles = (Get-ChildItem $dir -recurse | where-object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true })
$subFiles | % {
$path = $dir+$_
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
write-host "$_ Files:" $files.count
}
```